# 404 error with cross domain json calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7.5, jsonp

I have an ASP.NET MVC 2.0 application where I have an action that returns a jsonp action result. It worked on my development machine from  my local IIS web site to another IIS site.

When I deployed the services site on Windows Server 2008 R2+IIS7.5 the ajax calls don't work and I get this error:

> 404  The resource you are looking for
>   might have been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Update: Solved

The problem was with query string limits on IIS 7.5. You can adjust this by following the steps on this page:

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits

Comment: You should answer this question below and mark as accepted.

Comment: i know i still have to wait because my reputation is under 100 p

Comment: well and i can't accept my own answer before 2 days ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with query string limits on IIS 7.5. You can adjust this by following the steps on this page:

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits